# SwiftKey 3 randomly quits giving suggestions?

Tags: swiftkey

I just downloaded the new version of SwiftKey (3) on my HTC EVO running Cyanogenmod 7.1 (supersonic). <strike>I use GOSms for texting, and it gives me a popup whenever I receive a text, so I do not have to venture all the way to the messaging app. However, the word suggestions and autocorrect function (as are basically the point of using SwiftKey) do not function in the popup window, and only work after I go back to GOSms to reply there.</strike>

Occasionally and seemingly randomly, SwiftKey will not provide suggestions and autocorrect will not function. This usually requires exiting out of whatever is using the keyboard and re-entering that application.

Has anyone else experienced this or found a fix?